# GLPK - Most efficient way to only check for existance of a solution and not to actually optimize

Tags: glpk

Assuming that when using the GNU Linear Programming Toolkit, I do not want to optimize in an LP instance, but rather only want to check if there exists a solution (side note: I'm interested in problems in which all variables have real-valued upper and lower bounds, so the overall solution space is bounded).

What is the most efficient way to ask GLPK (using library calls) to check the feasibility of an LP instance? I am aware that there are functions such as "glp_adv_basis" and "glp_cpx_basis" that will try to find an initial solution. But I still need to call glp_solve to check for feasibility, and even when setting the optimization function to be the constant 0 function, GLPK may still perform some work to find an optimum in it. How do I ensure that it doesn't do so?

Another side note: I am using the C interface, if that makes any difference.